# Conditionally define variable in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to conditionally define a variable in an Ansible playbook like this:

```yml
my_var: "{{ 'foo' if my_condition}}"
```

I would like the variable to remain undefined if the condition does not resolve to `true`.

Ansible gives the following error if I try to execute the code:

```sh
fatal: [foo.local] => {'msg': 'AnsibleUndefinedVariable: One or more undefined
                       variables: the inline if-expression on line 1 evaluated
                       to false and no else section was defined.', 'failed': True}
```

Why is this an error anyway?

The complete case looks like this:

```yml
{role: foo, my_var: "foo"}
```

If `my_var` is defined, the role does something special. In some cases, I don't want the role to do this. I could use `when: condition`, but then I would have to copy the whole role block. I could also use an extra bool variable, but I would like a solution without having to change the "interface" to the role.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at: [Ansible: Set variable only if undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49653974/658497)

Comment: According to the Jinja Template Designer Documentation, "The else part is optional. If not provided, the else block implicitly evaluates into an Undefined object (regardless of what undefined in the environment is set to)". I guess for Ansible, Undefined is not allowed and you should use the else as indicated in the accepted answer. Weird thing is that this definitely works without the else in some Ansible installs like my own, but not the one at work.

Answer (score 102):

You could use something like this:

```yml
my_var: "{{ 'foo' if my_condition else '' }}"
```

The 'else' will happen if condition not match, and in this case will set a empty value for the variable. I think this is a short, readable and elegant solution.

Comment: And in case my_var should be set to other variables value, which might not been defined, try something like: `{{ var_a if var_a is defined else var_b | default('default value') }}`

Comment: can it be set to a dictionary in a similar way? Tried: `my_var: "{{ '{key1: value1, key2: value2 }' if my_condition }}"` without any luck (((

Comment: OP told you: "I would like the variable to remain undefined" and you answered with setting it to `''` instead.

Comment: @poige Undefined variable in Ansible is a tricky question because Ansible doesn't use a complete programming language. So the best you can do is set the value of the variable to an empty value or doesn't set the variable at all.

Answer (score 30):

This code may help you to define a variable with condition.

```yml
- hosts: node1
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
   - name: Check File
     shell: ls -ld /etc/postfix/post-install
     register: result
     ignore_errors: yes

   - name: Define Variable
     set_fact:
         exists: "{{ result.stdout }}"
     when: result|success

   - name: Display Variable
     debug: msg="{{ exists }}"
     ignore_errors: yes
```

So here the `exists` will display only if the condition is `true`.

Comment: I'd recommend using the stat module to check for the file rather than using the shell command.

Answer (score 21):

My example, after https://stackoverflow.com/a/43403229/5025060:

```
vars:
    sudoGroup: "{{ 'sudo' if ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu' else 'wheel' }}"
```

Because of the different sudo conventions used by Ubuntu versus other platforms, here I am telling Ansible to set a variable named `sudoGroup` to `sudo` if the platform is Ubuntu, otherwise set it to `wheel`.

Later in my playbook, I combine the variable with Ansible's `user` module to add either `sudo` or `wheel` to an account's secondary groups depending on the OS Ansible is running on:

```
- name: Add or update bob account
  user:
    name: bob
    uid: 3205
    groups: "{{ sudoGroup }}"
    append: yes
```

**NOTES:**

- *Double quotes* around the `{{ variable }}` are required in the `user: groups:` definition above.
- Once I define `sudoGroup` as above in my playbook's global `vars:` section, Ansible configures it at run time (based on `ansible_distribution`) for each target I define in my `hosts:` section.

Answer (score 17):

I believe you're after the `default(omit)` filter. ([Reference](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#omitting-parameters)).

As per the example, `mode` will behave like it wasn't set at all for the first two items in the loop.

```yml
- name: touch files with an optional mode
  file:
    dest: "{{item.path}}"
    state: touch
    mode: "{{item.mode|default(omit)}}"
  loop:
    - path: /tmp/foo
    - path: /tmp/bar
    - path: /tmp/baz
      mode: "0444"
```

Comment: You can also cram pretty much any other value in there (e.g. `foo | default(5)`) [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables).

Answer (score 4):

#### This can be set as with bool:

```
- name: Conditional (true and false)
  set_fact: 
      my_boolean_set_to_be: "{{ 'true' if my_var == 'foo' else 'false' }}"  

- name: Display Variable
  debug: msg="{{ my_boolean_set_to_be }}"
```

#### This can be set as for more conditionals like 'if-ifelse-else' statements:

```
- name: Conditional for 'my_var' (2 options and one default)
  set_fact: 
      my_var_set_to_be: "{{ 'breakfast' if my_var == 'morning' else 'lunch' if my_var == 'afternoon' else 'dinner' }}"  

- name: Display Variable
  debug: msg="{{ my_var_set_to_be }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like the variable to remain undefined if the condition does
> not resolve to true.

Then I would do that this way

```
- name: assign value to variable only if condition is met
  set_fact: 
    my_var: 'foo' 

  when: my_condition
```

example:

```
- name: if 'substring' is contained in my_string, then set my_var to '*'
  set_fact: 
    my_var: '*' 

  when: 'substring' in my_string
```

This is something I find useful when I want to reassign the value of a variable contained in a `vars_files` script.
I could not do it by simply defining the variable again, because ansible would complain about the not-unique variable name:

```
my_var: "{% if 'substring' in my_string %}*{% else %}{{ my_var }}{% endif %}"
# but my_var is already declared, so this task fails.
```