# Ansible: Set variable only if undefined

Tags: ansible

I would like to set an ansible variable to some default value but only if the variable is undefined. Otherwise I would like to keep it unchanged.

I tried these two approaches and both of them produce recursive loop:

```
namespace: "{{namespace|default(default_namespace)}}"
namespace: "{% if namespace is defined %}{{namespace}}{% else %}{{default_namespace}}{% endif %}"
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It seems like you are taking a wrong approach.

Take a look at the Ansible documentation concerning [variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). It is a built-in feature of Ansible to use the default variable if the variable is not defined.

In Ansible 2.x the variable precedence starts like this:

> role defaults
>
> inventory vars

So if you want to define a default value for a variable you should set it in `role/defaults/main.yml`. Ansible will use that value only if the variable is not defined somewhere else.

Another option is to use a [Jinja2 filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables). With a Jinja filter you can set a default value for a variable like this:

```
{{ some_variable | default(5) }}
```

Comment: Using the Jina2 filters is it possible to do something like 
`{{ variable | default(other_variable) }}`?

Comment: Yes it does, I assumed I would have to nest the curly braces which does not work.

Comment: Doesn't work if variable is nested like `{{ dict.key | default(5) }}`. It will fail if `dict` is undefined.

Answer (score 36):

```
- set_fact: namespace="default_namespace"
  when: namespace is undefined
```

Comment: I found this useful if I needed to modify variable A if variable B was set. (append flags to a command).

Answer (score 6):

Additional, in case you using lookup to define default variable (read from environment) you have also set the second parameter of default to `true`:

```
- set_facts:
    ansible_ssh_user: "{{ lookup('env', 'SSH_USER') | default('foo', true) }}"
```

You can also concatenate multiple default definitions together:

```
- set_facts:
    ansible_ssh_user: "{{ some_var.split('-')[1] | default(lookup('env','USER'), true) | default('foo') }}"
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you need to set your **variable by priority order**, likewise:

1. Set variable as var_priority_1.
   But if it is not defined, then:
2. Set variable as var_priority_2.
   But if it is not defined either, then:
3. Set variable to a default value.

I had to use such condition while trying to get value from inventory hosts variables, that sometimes need to be overridden by role vars:

```
shell: |
    ...
    shell_var={{ role_var if role_var is defined else hostvars[item].host_var | default('defalut_value') }}
    ...
  with_items: "{{ groups[hosts_group_iterator] }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly the case I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
shellvar = "{{ some_var | default(omit) }}"
``
from [this article][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55826235/1021535
```