# Ansible - skip undefined variable in dict

Tags: ansible

I`m using ipa_user module to setup users. There is variable passsword which force new password. 
For some users (when var is not in dict) I would like to skip it in iteration, but it always fail.

This is snippet from my playbook. Ansible version is 2.7

task:

```
- name: adding ipa users
  ipa_user:
    name: "{{ item.value.login }}"
    state: "{{ item.value.state }}"
    givenname: "{{ item.value.givenname }}"
    sn: "{{ item.value.surname }}"
    mail: "{{ item.value.mail }}"
    telephonenumber: "{{ item.value.telephonenumber }}"
    title: "{{ item.value.title }}"
    password: "{{ item.value.password }}" <<- to be skipped if not found
    ipa_host: ipa.gdi.telekom.de
    ipa_user: admin
    ipa_pass: "{{ ipa_pass }}"
  with_dict: "{{ipausers}}"
  when: item.key in ipausers.keys()
  register: output_ipa_users
```

Log:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'password'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/builds/gitlab/infra/user-management/roles/free-ipa/tasks/main.yml': line 13, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: adding ipa users\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Note: I tried it with:

```
with_dict: "{{ipausers|default({})}}"  
ignore_errors: yes
```

without success

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it'll be much help to you now but for others than stumble on this post, I ended up with something like below for a similar problem. I'm using Ansible 2.7.8.

```
- name: Creating user accounts...
  user:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: "{{ item.state }}"
    comment: "{{ item.comment | default(omit) }}"
    group: "{{ item.groups is defined | ternary((item.groups|default([]))[0], omit) }}"
    groups: "{{ item.groups | default(omit) }}"
    password: "{{ item.password_hash | default(omit) }}"
    uid: "{{ item.uid | default(omit) }}"
  with_items: "{{ managed_users }}"
```

The solution is
`group: "{{ item.groups is defined | ternary((item.groups|default([]))[0], omit) }}"`

If `groups` isn't in `item` then Ansible will omit the group part of this tasks but jinja2 will evaluate `item.groups[0]` anyway. So to allow for this we have to use `item.groups|default([])` so jinja2 uses an empty list when groups isn't defined instead of throwing a `'dict object' has no attribute` error. The omit part is similar to the  `default(omit)` filter where Ansible simply omits the option from the task.

Lubo's problem is a little simpler so using just default(omit) filter should work. That said as password is required so the entire task should be skipped with a conditional.

```
- name: adding ipa users
  ipa_user:
    name: "{{ item.value.login }}"
    state: "{{ item.value.state }}"
    givenname: "{{ item.value.givenname }}"
    sn: "{{ item.value.surname }}"
    mail: "{{ item.value.mail }}"
    telephonenumber: "{{ item.value.telephonenumber }}"
    title: "{{ item.value.title }}"
    password: "{{ item.value.password | default(omit) }}" #<-- would be omitted
    ipa_host: ipa.gdi.telekom.de
    ipa_user: admin
    ipa_pass: "{{ ipa_pass }}"
  with_dict: "{{ipausers}}"
  when: item.key in ipausers.keys() and item.key.password is defined #<-- second check for when password is not defined.
  register: output_ipa_users
```

Answer (score 1):

Make this attribute [optional](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional)

```yaml
    password: "{{ item.value.password|default(omit) }}"
```

To make a playbook or a role reusable it is a good idea to declare all parameters of a module in the task and *`default(omit)`* parameters that are not required.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely skip the `ipa_user` module execution when password is not defined, check for its presence in your `when` clause:

```
when: item.value.password | default('') | length > 0
```

If you want to execute the `ipa_user` module without specifying a password for user if it does not exists, use the [`omit` placeholder](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#omitting-parameters) in your module params:

```
password: "{{ item.value.password | default(omit) }}"
```

**Note**: your current `when` clause can be removed. It will always return true as you are looping over a dict and later checking if the current key in the loop is part of that dict.

Comment: Thanks. I have no errors with `ansible-playbook --check` (with omit), but finally it doesn`t work, because password cannot be empty. Is any chance during the loop just to ignore it, because password is not required field?

Comment: The second solution I gave is very exactly to ignore the password if it is not given. Please define "doesn't work" (e.g. error log, etc....)

Comment: Its here (reduced): `failed: [localhost] (---- {"changed": false, "item": {"key": "xyz", "value": {"givenname": "xyz", "login": "xyz", "mail": ["example@example.com"], "password": "", "state": "present", "surname": "xyz", "telephonenumber": ["+4"], "title": "DevOps Engineer"}}, "msg": "response user_mod: no modifications to be performed"}` (real data replaced). So, password is empty and that`s the problem.

Comment: This is completely different from your initial question. In your question, password is undefined. In your comment, password is an empty string. It will not be omitted in this case.