# Omitting parent of the parameter in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

Anyone has any idea how to use default(omit) [filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#omitting-parameters) to drop the parent parameter too? Similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55824820), the answer doesn't really answer the complexity of the problem I am facing though and I was rather abruptly disallowed to enhance the answer by asking a follow up question, hence the new question.

Here is the example ansible playbook task:

```
- name: Testing omit
  module:
    parameters:
      Parameter1:
        value: "{{ TemplateVariable | default(omit) }}"
```

When TemplateVariable is not defined this results in the following json passed through to another API:

```
parameters { "Parameter1": {} }
```

However I need this it to pass this:

```
parameters { }
```

The module requires a "value" parameter for every parameter defined. I cannot fix the module, anyone can suggest any Ansible/Jinja2/YAML workaround please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this ?

```yaml
- name: define module params for param1
  set_fact:
    module_params: "{{ module_params | default({}) | combine({ 'parameter1': { 'value': TemplateParam } }) }}"
  when: TemplateParam is defined

- name: eventually do this for next param2
  set_fact:
    module_params: "{{ module_params | default({}) | combine({ 'parameter2': { 'value': OtherParam } }) }}"
  when: OtherParam is defined

# Note you can organize the above in a loop if you have a lot of params.
# You will have to adapt the data structure and tests but it is quite straightforward.

 - name: Call module with calculated params
   module:
     parameters: "{{ module_params | default({}) }}"
```

Comment: Oh wow! If this work it is fantastic. I will test and report back, thank you!

Comment: Thank you, this worked very well! Just one snag I can't fix (edit requires changing at least 6 characters), you need to change last pair of brackets from ```})``` to ```}}``` in ```set_fact``` lines.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the feedback. If this fixes the issue, you should accept the answer so others know there is a working solution.

Comment: I am afraid I am not worthy accepting answers. I clicked to vote up but they say they don't care. "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Accepting and upvoting are two different actions: you can always accept answers to your question. Concerning upvoting, you should be good by now since you received up-votes yourself ;)

Comment: The tick was there now - sorry I am just a newbie. Anyway thank you for solving my problem!