# ansible - change precedence of role variables

Tags: ansible

I've created a role to install my apps.

This role needs specific variables defined in separate files in the vars dir of the role, depending of the app (here pdt_type), like that:

```
- name: Include pkg list of {{ pdt_type }}
  include_vars:
    file: "{{ pdt_type }}.yml"
```

It's working fine. But I'd like to be able to overload those variables of my role by the inventory ones. Or vars loaded by include_vars has a greater precedence of the inventory ones.

Do you know how I can do to change this behavior?
How I can defined default variables of a role based on a condition?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't change the [variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) in ansible and that's good.

> A lot of folks may ask about how variables override another. Ultimately it’s Ansible’s philosophy that it’s better you know where to put a variable, and then you have to think about it a lot less. [...] There is only one Empire State Building. One Mona Lisa, etc. Figure out where to define a variable, and don’t make it complicated.

For defining variables on a condition see:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/907164/ansible-conditionally-define-variables-in-vars-file-if-a-certain-condition-is-m
- [Conditionally define variable in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31310688/conditionally-define-variable-in-ansible)
- https://everythingshouldbevirtual.com/automation/ansible-using-set_facts-module/

For including variables conditionally from a file see:

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/include_vars_module.html

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But then, how I can define "default" variable of role depending of a certain condition. My app "one", does not take the same default var as my app "two"

Comment: Define a default in your role and overwrite it in your playbook.

Comment: But `include_default` does not exist, no? Because I need to include default var file based on a specific var.

Comment: See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/include_vars_module.html

Comment: Unfortunately `include_vars` has a greater precedence than the inventory one. So it does not answer my problem.